# Find residue of $\frac{z-\sin(z)}{z}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the residue at $z=0$ of the function $$\frac{z-\sin(z)}{z}$$

Approach: $\frac{z-\sin(z)}{z}=1-\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=$

$n=-1/2$ at $1/z$, so the coefficient will be $(-1)^{-1/2}*(1)$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: $\frac{z-\sin z}{z}$ is holomorphic at zero, so there is no residue.

Comment: Can you justify your claim from the point of view of residues?. For example I realize that n may just be allowed to be positive since $(-1)^n$ when n is negative gives a complex number

Comment: Your sum is n=1 to infinity. How can you write n=-0.5?

Comment: UMMM. Yes. That's true, so negative powers don't exist which imply that the constant is 0

Comment: Exactly. Your calculations already show that the residue $a_{-1} = 0$. Small mistake: $-\sum (-1)^n(\cdots) = \sum (-1)^{n+1}(\cdots)$

Comment: @carmichael561 No, it's not, it's not defined at 0. (Yes, I know that 0 is a removable singularity, but still.)